# Array.find() is changing objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to find objects from an original array named 'value' where the value of a property matches what I am looking for, and then add these found objects to a 'resultArray'.

However after running the code below all objects inside resultArray are the same object. I have confirmed while debugging that 'value' contains different objects all with different property values and propValues contains multiple different values.

Does anyone know how this could be possible?

```
for (let propValue of propValues) {
    let foundObj = value.find(obj => obj[propName] = propValue);
    resultArray.push(foundObj);
}
return resultArray;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
obj[propName] = propValue
```

One equal sign `=` is for assignment, use two `==` for equality checking or preferably three `===` for strict equality checking.

Answer (score 1):

Single equal sign serves as an assign operator - you're reassigning the value while looping. Use `==` for loose comparison (types are coalesced together and then the two values are compared, i.e. a check for `1 == '1'` will return `true`) or `===` for strict comparison (won't return `true` unless both operands are equal **and** of the same type).

It is not `Array.find()` itself that's mutating the input, it's the callback function you pass to it.